# parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: php, json, ajax

I hava an ajax function :

```js
$.ajax({
     url: 'my.php',
     type:'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data:{switch:9},
      error: function(data,e,f){
        alert("Error : "+e+" "+f);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      },

     success:function(data){
            if(data.length!=0){
              
            
                // getting the data from the array
                $.each(data, function(k, v) { 
                     // set the data from database to input box
                     $("input[name='fname']").val(v['fname']); 
                     $("input[name='bname']").val(v['bname']); 
                     $("input[name='address']").val(v['address']); 
                     $("input[name='phone']").val(v['phone_no']); 
                     $("input[name='website']").val(v['website']); 
                     $("input[name='ein_ss_no']").val(v['ein_ss_no']); 
                     $(".user-catagory").val(v['business_type']).change(); 
                });
            }
            } // End of success function of ajax 1 form

  });
```

This ajax function fetch data from php server in the form of json and then append the data to input text fields. This ajax function work fine some time and append the data into text fields but some it give this error "parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". When i console it data respone it show me my whole html code like this

```js
00:24:17.314 {"readyState":4,"responseText":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\n\n<!-- title -->\n<title></title>\n\n<!-- css link -->\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"web_assets/css/bootstrap.css\">\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"web_assets/css/custom.css\">\n\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"assets/js/jquery.min.js\"></script>\n                \n        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"assets/js/bootstrap.min3.js\"></script>\n        <link rel='stylesheet' href='ASLibrary/css/style3.css' type='text/css' media='all' />\n               \n        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"assets/js/respond.min.js\"></script>\n        <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n            var $_lang = {\"email\":\"Email\",\"login\":\"Login\",\"username\":\"Username\",\"password\":\"Password\",\"your_email\":\"Your Email\",\"login_with\":\"Login With[…]1 add_profile.js:10:9
```

.... so on.
I am totally confuse why my code is running and not running some.
please if anyone know about it please help me.

Comment: Look at what the full HTML code says. It looks like a login page. Are you sure that when this problem occurs, the session hasn't just timed out and the request is redirecting to a login page?

Comment: but sir how it's going on as i directly go to this page after login. Is this a server issue?